# How to swizzle []method of NSArray in iOS11?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I used to hack the method like

```
Method originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod([NSArray class], @selector(objectAtIndexedSubscript:));
Method swapMethod = class_getInstanceMethod([NSArray class], @selector(objectAtIndexedSubscriptNew:));
method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swapMethod);
```

It works fine in the iOS10 and before, but it can't work in the iOS11, is that any other way we can swizzle the [] method in iOS11?

Comment: Works fine on iOS 11.. I just tested it. You need to make sure this is only called once.

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 11, for some reason that I'm still researching, swizzle methods should only be called once.

```
static dispatch_once_t once;
dispatch_once(&once, ^{    
    Method originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod([NSArray class], @selector(objectAtIndexedSubscript:));
    Method swapMethod = class_getInstanceMethod([NSArray class], @selector(objectAtIndexedSubscriptNew:));
    method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swapMethod);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I change the class from `[NSArray class]` to `NSClassFromString(@"__NSArrayI")` and it works fine now.